# How to share the LSP for all instances of neovim?

Tags: linux, text-editor, neovim, language-server-protocol, rust-analyzer

I'm using neovim as main text editor, and rust-analyzer as LSP for rust file type. All works fine, but each instance of neovim starts its own instance of LSP, and this takes a lot of resources.

So the question is, what is the way to make once instance of rust-analyzer accessible for all neovim instances?